# Changing layout parameters inside a fragment with a button's onClick method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, onclick

I have an activity that bears exactly 5 fragments. In one of these fragments there is a `Button` and a `RelativeLayout`. I want my button to be able to change this `RelativeLayout`'s height or width.

my xml:

```
     <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sSumBut"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:onClick="onClick" >
</Button>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/sSum"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

</RelativeLayout>


      </LinearLayout>

         </ScrollView>
```

As you see the height of the `RelativeLayout` is 0. I want the button to be able to change it to 100dp.

This is my `Fragment` class:

```
  @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.up, container, false);

  Button sButton = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.sSumBut);
  final RelativeLayout sSummary = (RelativeLayout) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.sSum);

  sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // When button is clicked.
            sSummary.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(250, 250));
        }
    });
```

But this gives out the error  `Cannot refer to a non-final variable` and if I make the variable final, I normally can't change it inside the `onClick` method dynamically. Please considering that this class is a `Fragment`, how can I work around this?

error log:

```
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:360)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1284)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:354)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1451)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:847)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1868)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
       11-01 15:07:03.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3048):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: if you make Sum final, you can still access it self and its methods/childs. you just cant change the object itself, for example this would not work: final Object x = null; x = new Object(); because it's "final" declared as null. But final CustomObject y = new CustomObject(); y.changeProperties(); y.doSomething(); still works.

Comment: @damian I did what you said but it crashed again, I posted the error log, could you please check it out?

Comment: can you show your XML layout?

Comment: @damian of course, here you are

Comment: i dont see a relativelayout with the id Sum, are you sure its not a type -> aSum or sSum or something?

Comment: @damian ah I am sorry, the first relativelayout's id is in fact Sum, this was a bit of an old version xml. I in fact can reach the button. it crashes as soon as I click the button.

Comment: so can you post the updated code? exception says there's some sort of casting mistake, so it could pretty easy be a simple typo or a wrong ID / view you're fetching.

Comment: @damian once again here you are, I also updated the fragment class code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sSummary.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(250, 250));
```

Your `sSummary`, even if it is a `RelativeLayout`, is inside a `LinearLayout`. A view's layout params refer to the *parent* layout so the correct type of layout params here would be `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. This is what causes the class cast exception.

Often a good approach is to just modify the existing layout params as retrieved with `getLayoutParams()`. After modifying the returned params in-place, request a re-layout with `requestLayout()` (`setLayoutParams()` also does this implicitly).

Comment: this is the second time you "actually" solve my problem :D thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting an error is because you can't reference a variable within the OnClickListener that is instantiated outside of class without it being final.

The fact that it is a `Fragment` shouldn't change anything, it's just a matter of correctness. you could simply make the following update:

```
final RelativeLayout Sum = (RelativeLayout) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Sum);
```

And that should fix the error that you are receiving.

Comment: I did what you said but it crashed again, I posted the error log, could you please check it out?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out the problem was `LinearLayout` for some reason. I changed it to `RelativeLayout` and my problem was fixed. What the hell `LinearLayout`? I trusted you.